Maximum-period rotate-add RNG
I've experimentally verified that the following (incredibly simple) PRNG can have period  $2^w - 1$ for $w = 8$ and $w = 16$, for appropriate choices of $r, c$, where $0 < r < w$:
$$x \leftarrow (x \ggg r) + c \mod 2^{w}$$
Here $\ggg$ indicates bit rotation.  For example, for $w = 8$ the only choices are $r \in \{3, 5\}$ with $c = \{92, 106, 150, 164\}$. Interestingly for each $c$ both choices of $r$ work.
The smallest $c$ that works for $w = 16$ is $c = 19422$ with $r \in \{5, 11\}$.
Is there some sort of pattern found in which $r, c$ form a period $2^w - 1$ RNG, and/or an efficient way of finding an $r, c$ that has that period for a given $w$ (especially for $w = 64$)?

Some conjectures: if $r$ has a maximal period, so does $w - r$. If $c$ has a maximal period, $2^w - c$ also does.

This is not secure PRNG, as for any given output, the next output is predictable. Unless you do not plan to use it for non cryptographic use cases. You can look at https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/531 there are some clues of how to implement cheap PRNG and how to test their performance.

@EvgeniVaknin I never claimed it was secure, nor am I planning to use it for that. Your linked paper does not help in establishing whether a certain $c$ is a maximal-period one, which is what this question asks.

FWIW this is similar to constructions proposed in 4.2.1 and 5.4 of Hars-Petruska but only invertibility was considered there, not period. It seems difficult to analyze.
